# Problems with exception handling using try and catch

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to use `try` and `catch`. If the entered input isn't valid the loop sould repeat and ask the user for input again, but it's not working. When I type something wrong it just repeats the `System.out.println`.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Price
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        userInput();
    }
    public static void userInput()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 1;
        int month, day, year;

        do {
            try {    
                System.out.println("Please enter a month MM: ");
                month = scan.nextInt();

                if(month>12 && month<1)
                {
                    System.out.println("FLOP");
                } 
                x=2;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("not today mate");
            }
        }
        while(x==1);             
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your code and fix your indentation so that your code is readable. Each code block should be indented exactly the same amount. Come on now, if you're asking for free advice, the least you can do is put in the effort so that your code is readable.

Comment: And what do you mean with *not working*?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Or you could take 10 seconds and format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a working solution to your problem

```
public static void userInput(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 1;
        int month, day, year;

        System.out.println("Please enter a month MM: ");
        month = scan.nextInt();
        boolean i = true;
        while(i == true)
        {
            if(month < 12 && month > 1)
            {
                System.out.println("FLOP");
                i = false;
            }
            else if(month >= 12 || month <= 1)
            {
                System.out.println("not today mate");
                month = scan.nextInt();                
            }
        }     

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, exceptions are used for exceptional circumstances, not to drive the logic of a program.  Validating inputted data is not an exceptional circumstance in this case.  It's a normal state of affairs that a user might make an error and enter an incorrect number.  Put the input in a loop and repeat until a correct value is entered (perhaps with an option for the user to cancel).

Answer (score 0):

First your condition is wrong.

You have:

```
if(month>12 && month<1)
{
  System.out.println("FLOP");
}
```

So month cannot be bigger than 12 and at the same time less than 1.

I think you wanted to put OR instead of AND, e.g.

```
if(month > 12 || month < 1)
{
  System.out.println("FLOP");
}
```

As for the exception, it might occur when user enters non numeric value or input is exausted.
Throws:
InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range
NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted
IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed

Comment: what he meant was correct, it just was not properly structured. He wanted a condition that if some value is less then 12 but ( and ) more then 1. Other condition would be or (if something is more than 12 or less then 1).